# How did Rose Armitage get away with it?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-out

In [Get Out](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5052448/?ref_=nv_sr_1), we find that

> Rose Armitage has led several black men (and even one woman) to the house for the Coagula procedure.

How have none of the missing persons been ever associated with Rose? Surely, friends of the targets would know about Rose, and the police would inquire about the missing people. She would be associated with several missing people, surely decent police officers would find this suspicious.

I also admit that it is possible that she has been found suspicious previously, but got away with it due to lack of proof or great lawyers (rich family). Is there any information on this topic?

Comment: +1 I didn't even think about that. How would she explain it to their friends (who obviously know her). My guess is that she uses an alias each time, changes appearance slightly and moves to different areas.

Comment: I see one of the main themes of the movie as being that young white women will be assumed to be victims and never criminals, and young black men will be assumed to criminals and never victims, in general. This is communicated throughout the movie, but most especially at the very end when the police car shows up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this [wikia](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Armitage):

> When Rose prevents a police officer from checking Chris' ID, she seems to be defending him from a racist policeman, when in actuality, she doesn't want any record of Chris' location, in case law enforcement attempts to look for him when he goes missing.

This means she is very careful while hunting (she probably uses fake names, hunt people far away from her hometown, ...).

Also, the movie deals with the topic of racism and that black people's lives aren't as important as whites' are. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Out#Themes):

> The film also depicts the lack of attention on missing black Americans compared to missing white females. Slate's Damon Young stated the film's premise was *"depressingly plausible ... Although black people only comprise 13 percent of America's population, they are 34 percent of America's missing, a reality that exists as the result of a mélange of racial and socioeconomic factors rendering black lives demonstratively less valuable than the lives [of] our white counterparts."*<sup>[full Slate article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2017/03/10/get_out_and_america_s_many_missing_black_people.html)</sup>

This is humorously shown in the film: When Rod Williams recognizes Logan as missing (for several months) person Andre Hayworth, suspecting a conspiracy, Rod goes to the police but is derided (i.e. the police didn't care at all).

Comment: Armitage seems to be the real family name though. In the "Behold the Coagula" video the grandfather calls himself Roman Armitage. And in the pictures Chris finds Rose looks the same (no disguises). - None of the three police officers that hear Rod's story is white, so at least in this case I don't think it was about racism.

Comment: 1. Rod already knows where Chris is. 2. Chris calling 911 and Rose immediately showing up with a gun seems to suggest that the local cops are in on it 3. Rod was dismissed because he included the "sex slave" part of his theory.